# Was the "Gospel of Hebrews" ever considered to be inspired?

Tags: church-history, early-church, church-fathers, ecclesiology

The "Gospel of the Hebrews" has [several quotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_the_Hebrews#:%7E:text=The%20gospel%20emphasizes%20the%20fulfillment,%22rest%22%20and%20reigns%20forever.) from early church fathers. Did they ever believe it to be Inspired and equal to the traditional four gospels? Or did they view it as supplementary material that is likely to be true.

Comment: Here is a useful article about the place of the Hebrew Gospel in Church history. https://lukeprimacy.com/hebrew-gospel/#:~:text=Despite%20its%20non%2Dcanonical%20status,canon%2C%20used%20in%20patristic%20writings.

Comment: The article above provides evidence that the Hebrew Gospel was one of the primary sources consulted by Luke when writing his gospel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most scholars believe the Gospel of the Hebrews was composed in the late first or early second century and that its content was based on independent traditions about Jesus. Several of the early church fathers briefly quoted the Gospel of the Hebrews, but no copies of the book exist.

> Some scholars believe that the Gospel of the Hebrews was originally written in Greek, although Jerome indicates that he had translated it from Hebrew (On Famous Men, 2–3). Jerome called it “the Gospel according to the Hebrews, which is written in the Chaldee and Syrian language, but in Hebrew characters, and is used by the Nazarenes to this day” (Against the Pelagians III:2). According to the historian Eusebius, the early church father Papias claimed that Matthew had originally recorded Jesus’ words in the Hebrew language (History, III:39.16). There is still much uncertainty concerning the origin and content of the Gospel of the Hebrews, in light of the current lack of manuscripts.

> The Gospel of the Hebrews seems to have been oriented toward Jewish Christians. Some of the quotes are similar to Jewish wisdom literature. Jerome relates that, in the Gospel of the Hebrews’ resurrection account, the Lord’s brother James is prominent (On Famous Men, 2); this fact suggests a Jewish-Christian influence in the book. Despite the handful of allusions to it in early church writings, the Gospel of the Hebrews was never considered canonical. Origen cast doubt on the veracity of the book in that he preceded a quotation from it with the words “If any one should lend credence to the Gospel according to the Hebrews” (Commentary on the Gospel of John, II:6).

Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/gospel-of-the-Hebrews.html

From the article above, the conclusion is that the early church ultimately rejected the Gospel of the Hebrews and it is not consideredto be inspired by God.